# Pandas - Compare two DFs of unequal legnth with df.compare

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df_1 = {'budget_id':['1', '2', '3', '4'], 
        'budget_amount':[200, 300, 400, 500]} 

df_2 = {'budget_id':['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], 
        'budget_amount':[200, 300, 400, 550, 700]} 

df_1.compare(df_2, align_axis=0, keep_equal=True).rename(index={'self': 'Prev', 'other': 'New'}, level=1)
```

Desired output of df.compare():

```
budget_id budget_amount
4         550
5         700
```

I have two data frames that I wish to compare using df.compare. They both have the same columns and index labels.

However, I can not guarantee they have the same number of rows. This causes issues as compare expects a two DFs with the same shape.

I need to know if a new row has been added as part of the compare.

Is the best solution would be to append blank rows to either data frame until they're equal? How would you do that?

Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Sample data please. Also, `same index` with `possibly different length` suggests duplicate index. It doesn't really make sense how you would compare the two dataframes, unless one of them has unique index.

Comment: You're right, I should've said same index labels. The index itself would be unique for example df_1 might have a new entry added with a new unique index.

Comment: Could be an option to concatenate the two dataframe and remove duplicates in order to count the different rows?

Comment: You should **add** sample data and expected output. The question now is a bit too vague...

Comment: Just added some sample data and output. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I wrote based on Giovanni Frison's comment.

```
def compare_dataframes(df_1, df_2):
  if df_1.equals(df_2):
    return pandas.DataFrame()
  else:
    #Get indexes of rows present in df_2, but not in df_1
    new_row_indexes = df_2.index.difference(df_1.index) 
    new_rows = df_2.loc[new_row_indexes]

    #Create second index to match df.compare output
    new_rows[''] = 'New'
    new_rows = new_rows.set_index('',append=True)

    #Drop new rows from df_2 to create same shape for df.compare
    df_2 = df_2.drop(new_row_indexes)

    compare_df = df_1.compare(df_2, align_axis=0, keep_equal=True).rename(index={'self': 'Prev', 'other': 'New'}, level=1)
    compare_df = compare_df.append(new_rows)
    return compare_df
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `merge`work for you:

```
(df_1.merge(df_2, on='budget_id', how='right')
     .query('budget_amount_x != budget_amount_y')
)
```

Output:

```
  budget_id  budget_amount_x  budget_amount_y
3         4            500.0              550
4         5              NaN              700
```